# how to assemble angularjs directives and angular components together?

Tags: angularjs, angular, hybrid

I added angular component (ngcomponent1) into angularjs directive(jsdirective1), then I tried adding another angularjs directive(jsdirective2) into ngcomponent1. I have encountered the following figure. I do not have any information how to combine those directives and components in multiple layers. I know how to integrate one directive or component into component or directive, but not multi layers like this. If anyone has experience, could you give some guidance about it?

[image]